# How to convert List<Set<String>> to List<List<String>> in java?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

How can we convert List<Set> to List<List> in java easily?
Context: I came across this issue where I have generated List<Set> while in function return expects List<List>.

Answer (score 2):

Do you care about order in the `Set`s? If you do, you'll have to make sure you don't have them as Sets in the first place. If you don't, you can use the Java 8+ streams API:

```
list.stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or a `for` loop.

Comment: LinkedHashSet maintains order.

Comment: True, implementations of Set may preserve order, but in general the Set interface makes no guarantees about preserving order.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a Set to a List, you can simply do `new ArrayList<>(mySet)`. So you can do something like:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("c", "d"));
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<Set<String>> listOfSets = new ArrayList<>();
listOfSets.add(set1);
listOfSets.add(set2);
for (Set<String> set : listOfSets) {
    result.add(new ArrayList<>(set));
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `[[a, b], [c, d]]`

Comment: or ```List<List<String>> result = listOfSets.stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList());```